# hide and show bootstrap alert using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to hide and show bootstrap alert using javascript instead of using javascript alert prompt i want to user the bootstrap alert

before i asked this question. i searched how to do it but no luck!

thank you

this is the aspx code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" id="alertname" runat="server" visible="false">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
                    Enter a valid Name 
                </div>
<input type="text" runat="server"  onkeypress="return isAlphaNumeric(event)" class="form-control" id="txtname" placeholder="Signatory Name" />
```

this is the javascript code(instead of showing javascript alert prompt i want to show the bootstrap alert)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function isAlphaNumeric(e) {
            var key;

            if (window.event) {

                key = window.event.keyCode; //IE

            }

            else {

                key = e.which; //firefox

            }

            if (!((key > 64 && key <= 90) || (key > 96 && key <= 122) || (key == 32) || (key > 47 && key <= 57) || (key == 8) || (key == 0) || (key == 127))) {
                //document.getElementById('alertsignatoryname').style.visibility = 'visible'
                //document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";

                //alert(" You can enter only characters a to z,A to Z,0 to 9, and Space ");

                return false;

            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply use .show() and .hide() (if using jquery)

```
$('#alertname').show();
```

Comment: Not sure why, I tested this using your code and it works fine for me. Are you getting any errors? Are you using jquery? These are relevant things to put in your initial post

Comment: can you teach me how to catch error? or can you please upload the sample code and ill try to look whats lack on my code? thank you